# What could be causing an "unresolved external symbol IID_ICallbackWithNoReentrancyToApplicationSTA" error?

Tags: c++-winrt, ppl

Just googling or duckduckgo'ing

> unresolved external symbol `IID_ICallbackWithNoReentrancyToApplicationSTA`

Only brings up a single direct hit and that doesn't even help the person reporting the problem, so I'm hoping some C++/WinRT people run across this question.

While I can't share all the source (tons of interweaved proprietary files) I can share the scenario and a breakdown of what the code changes were; also, there's very little mention of `IID_ICallbackWithNoReentrancyToApplicationSTA` anywhere. Coincidentally, it [appears on GitHub](https://github.com/search?q=ICallbackWithNoReentrancyToApplicationSTA&type=Code) for some [Kenny Kerr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/500701/kenny-kerr) stuff. The project I'm having problems with is a C++/WinRT project, so that seems like a relevant trapping, especially since there are mentions of `xlang` which is supposed to be an abstraction of C++/WinRT.

**Scenario**: A C++/WinRT library is being consumed by a One Core UAP C++/WinRT application/service. The build breaks when trying to use the lib created by the library when building the app/service.

**Code Changes**: I implemented some PPL tasks into the library, specifically some `concurrency::task<void>` that do some I/O on a new thread used in the C++/WinRT lib that is being consumed by the app/service. It's an std::thread that uses a lambda that takes copies of objects and performs I/O. Something like this:

```
std::thread writer([content_vector, json_string, content_file_name, json_file_name]() {
        auto write_content = Helper_IO::Overwrite_Lines_Concurrent(content_file_name, content_vector);
        auto write_json = Helper_IO::Overwrite_File_Concurrent(json_file_name, json_string);
        write_content.get();
        write_json.get();
    });
```

`Helper_IO::Overwrite_*_Concurrent` are both static and both return a `concurrency::task<void>`

I've tried using `writer.detach()` and `writer.join()`, but the results are the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use Project > Properties > Linker > Input > "Additional Dependencies" setting, add `uuid.lib`.

Some background, identifiers whose names start with "IID" are {guids}.  Data, not code.  The MSDN documentation is often inadequate to tell you what library you need to link, too focused on documenting functions.  My favorite technique is to use a grep-like tool (I use the Far file manager, a bit to obscure to recommend) and search the SDK's lib directory for the string.

Comment: The project this is occurring in is a Static Library proj for C++/WinRT, and I'm not sure what VS template was used to make it but it lacks a "Linker" section, and I didn't see any areas for adding libs. Would using, `#pragma comment(lib, "uuid");` suffice? If not, what do you suggest?

Comment: Sigh, you cannot get a "unresolved external symbol" error from a static library project.  It is a linker error.  Copy/paste more from the Output window into your question so we can see what is getting linked.

Comment: My mistake. The error is being triggered while using something from the static lib, but the actual error is happening in the windows service that consumes that static lib. Thanks for clarifying!